# How to upload a Data Set to Azure Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am working with Azure Cloud Jupyter Notebook but i dont know how to read my data set so i need to know how to upload my csv dataset

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found in the [FAQ online](https://notebooks.azure.com/faq):

> **How can I upload my data and access it in a notebook?**
>
> A file can be added to the project itself from either the web or computer, or uploaded using the File Menu inside a JupyterNotebook if you chose to save under the project/ folder. Files outside the project/ folder will not be persisted. If you have multiple files that add up to over 100mb you'll need to upload them one by one.
>
> You can also download data using the terminal or shell commands inside of a notebook from publicly accessible web sites include GitHub, Azure blob storage, nasa.gov, etc...
>
> [image: Azure notebook - GIF]

Comment: Thanks,but that option is no longer there